# Adding a face in Photos

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I am running macOS El Capitan 10.11.5, and in Photos I am unable to add a face. When I go open the ‘Info’ window, I do not get the option to add a face.

I can only add a description or a keyword, and assign a location, but not add a face.

Some faces have been automatically detected, including objects like car wheels, but several faces have been ignored. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to blow up the photo to add Faces to them. Just double-click the photo, and **⊕ Add Faces** will appear in the Info panel between **Add Keyword** and **Assign a Location**.